# Applying the Implicit or Inverse function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

So, I am trying to show the following:

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^{1}$ function on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ where $f(0) = 0$.  Let $g: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a $C^{1}$ function such that $g(x) = (g_{1}(x),g_{2}(x),...,g_{n}(x))$.  Assume that $g(0) = 0$ and $Dg(0)$ is invertible.  Show that there exists and open neighborhood $U$ of the origin in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and a continuous function $h(x) = (h_{1}(x),h_{2}(x),...,h_{n}(x)): U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that
\begin{align}
f(x) = g(x) \cdot h(x).
\end{align}
for $x \in U$.

So, right away, the inverse function theorem applies to the function $g$.  However, I am not sure on how to best proceed from there.  I have considered setting up a function $F(u,x) = f(x) - u(g(x))$.  However, that function does not have desirable domain and range for the implicit function theorem.

Any hints or answers are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Solve this first if $g(x)=x$, and then reduce to this case by applying the Inverse Function Theorem. Do you know how to write $f(x) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_ih_i(x)$?

As a further hint for the latter: Write $f(x) = \displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac d{dt} f(tx)\,dt$.

Comment: I don't think I can write $f(x)$ that way off the top of my head.

Comment: See my addition :)

Comment: Thanks Ted.  Do you mean solve first as if $g$ were the identity?

Comment: Yes. Precisely.

Comment: So if I solve this problem with the $g$ the identity, there is really no problem because then the inverse function theorem gives me a $C^{1}$ diffeomorphism from $U$ to $V$ where $U$ and $V$ are both neighborhoods of $(0,0)$, so I can take $\bar{g} = h(g(x)) \equiv I?$

Comment: First, you don't want $h$ here. Suppose $g(\psi(x))=x$. Apply our previous result to $f\circ\psi$.

Comment: @DRich: Did you ever get this figured out?